# "especially" or "especially for"?

Tags: grammar

I'm confused about when I should use "especially" and when use the other.

For instance:

> I like fruits, ____ dragonfruits.
>
> We all like fruits, ____ me.

If I should use the same thing in these sentences, could you give me another example to illustrate how to use the other?

Answer (score 1):

> I like fruit, especially dragonfruit.

The last phrase means roughly "I especially like dragonfruit", and no preposition "for" is needed

> We all like fruit, especially me.

The final phrase is roughly equivalent to "I especially like fruits". Again there is no prepostion. (but with no explicit verb, the pronoun takes the default object form)

> This fruit is something new for all of us, especially for me.

Here the last phrase means "It is especially new for me".  The prepostion is required, and so it is also required in the shortened form.

Comment: Bit of a major edit... but better than writing a new answer to an old question.

Comment: This answer is wrong; the preposition is NOT required in the last example. It would be fine to say, "This fruit is something new for all of us, especially me."